# Create XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement, linq-group

I have a table (datatable)which looks like this

```
 Hotelid    Room#   Description visitor Name    amount
    1          2    of             5    sam     10 
    1          2    of             5    sam      5
    1          2    of             5    sam     50
    1          2    of             8    james   50
    1          2    of             8    james   50
    1          2    of             6    justin  50
    2          3    sm             4    john     5
    2          4    al             3    jose     8
    3          5    ms             2    tim     10
    3          5    ms             7    tom     20
```

I want to create an XML out of it. I am using LINQ for this and I am totally confused and tired. I am not getting it

```
<Hotels>
    <Hotel id="1" room="2" description="of">
    <Room="2" descr="of" visitor="5" name="sam"/>
        <fine amount="10"/>
        <fine amount="5"/>
        <fine amount="50"/>
        <Room="2" descr="of" visitor="8" name="james"/>
         <fine amount="50"/>
        <fine amount="50"/>
        <Room="2" descr="of" visitor="6" name="justin"/>
        <fine amount="50"/>
        </hotel>
        <Hotel id="2" room="3" description="sm">
        <Room="3" descr="sm" visitor="4" name="john"/>
        <fine amount="5"/>
        </hotel>
        <Hotel id="2" room="4" description="al">
        <Room="4" descr="al" visitor="3" name="jose"/>
        <fine amount="8"/>
        </hotel>

        <Hotel id="3" room="5" description="ms">
        <Room="5" descr="ms" visitor="2" name="tim"/>
        <fine amount="10"/>
        <Room="5" descr="ms" visitor="7" name="tom"/>
        <fine amount="20"/>
        </hotel>
    </Hotels>
```

This is what my code looks like this

```
   var query =
    from row in Hotels.AsEnumerable()
    group row by new
    {
        Hotelid = row.Field<string>("Hotelid"),
        room = row.Field<string>("room"),
        descr = row.Field<string>("descr"),
    }
        into g
        select new XElement("Hotel",
                new XAttribute("Hotelid", g.Key.Hotelid),
                new XAttribute("room", g.Key.room),
                new XAttribute("desc", g.Key.desc),
                from row in g
                    select new XElement(
                    "Room",
                    new XAttribute("room", row.Field<string>("room#")),
                    new XAttribute("desc", row.Field<string>("desc")),
                    new XAttribute("visitor", row.Field<string>("visitor")),
                    new XAttribute("name", row.Field<string>("name")),
                from row in g 
                    select new XElement(
                    "fine",
                    new XAttribute("amount", row.Field<string>("amount"))));

                    var document = new XDocument(new XElement("Hotels", query));
```

But I am getting multiple nodes for "room" with the same value. Any help???? :(

Comment: Is there a reason you're electing to use LINQ?

Comment: No particular reason. I thought it will be more simpler using LINQ to create XML.

Comment: The why is clear, just look at the RoomId column. No attempt to make it distinct. Also your target XML is not cosher. Why repeat RoomId and descriptin in the Hotel tag?

Comment: what is Room="5"? Isn't that Room id="5"?

Answer (score 0):

hahaha, I think I've lost a little sanity coming up with this bad-boy.  Let me know if it helps you.

```
void Main()
{
    var query =
    from row in Hotels.AsEnumerable()
    group row by new
    {
        row.Hotelid, row.Room, row.Description
    }
        into g
        select new XElement("Hotel",
                new XAttribute("Hotelid", g.Key.Hotelid),
                new XAttribute("room", g.Key.Room),
                new XAttribute("desc", g.Key.Description),
                from row in g
                    group row by new {row.Room, row.Description, row.Visitor, row.Name} into r
                    select new XElement(
                    "Room",
                    new XAttribute("room", r.Key.Room),
                    new XAttribute("desc", r.Key.Description),
                    new XAttribute("visitor", r.Key.Visitor),
                    new XAttribute("name", r.Key.Name),
                    new XAttribute("fineSum", r.Sum (x => x.Amount)),
                    from row in r                   
                    group row by new {row.Amount} into a
                    select new XElement("fine", a.Key.Amount )
              ));

    var document = new XDocument(new XElement("Hotels", query));                    

}
```

---

Sorry, forgot you're using a DataTable...

```
void Main()
{

    var query =
    from row in Hotels.AsEnumerable()
    group row by new
    {
        Hotelid = row.Field<string>("Hotelid"),
        room = row.Field<string>("room"),
        descr = row.Field<string>("Description")        
    }
        into g
        select new XElement("Hotel",
                new XAttribute("Hotelid", g.Key.Hotelid),
                new XAttribute("room", g.Key.room),
                new XAttribute("desc", g.Key.descr),
                from row in g
                    group row by new {
                        room = row.Field<string>("Room"),
                        descr = row.Field<string>("Description"), 
                        visitor = row.Field<string>("Visitor"), 
                        name = row.Field<string>("Name")
                    } into r
                    select new XElement(
                    "Room",
                    new XAttribute("room", r.Key.room),
                    new XAttribute("desc", r.Key.descr),
                    new XAttribute("visitor", r.Key.visitor),
                    new XAttribute("name", r.Key.name),
                    new XAttribute("fineSum", r.Sum (x => x.Field<int>("Amount"))),
                    from row in r                   
                    group row by new {fine = row.Field<int>("Amount")} into a
                    select new XElement("fine", a.Key.fine)
              ));

    var document = new XDocument(new XElement("Hotels", query));                    

}

// Define other methods and classes here
```